# Dismiss loadingController from external provider

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have implemented a provider which uses loadingController.

I'm able to show the loading screen but unable to dismiss it.

Currently I'm getting this error:

[image]

Code as follows:

```
export class CommonsProvider {
  constructor(private toast: Toast,public loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {  
  }

  showLoading(controlVariable,textToDisplay){
    controlVariable = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: textToDisplay
    });
    controlVariable.present();
  }

  cancelLoading(controlVariable){
    console.log("controlVariable",controlVariable);
    controlVariable.dismiss();
  }
```

.TS (neither the following 2 below is able to work)

```
this.commonsProvider.showLoading("getUserAccount","Please wait...");
this.commonsProvider.cancelLoading("getUserAccount");
```

or

```
test:any;
...
this.test =this.commonsProvider.showLoading("getUserAccount","Please wait...");
this.commonsProvider.cancelLoading(this.test);
```

Comment: where is `controlVariable ` declared?

Comment: @SurajRao not declared as it's a function variable, i might be wrong.

Comment: you need it as class variable the way you are using

Comment: any examples if possible?

Comment: just set `public controlVariable:any;` and in your function refer as `this.controlVariable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Suraj Rao ,

Using

`public controlVariable:any;` and in your function refer as `this.controlVariable` works.

Code:

```
cancelLoading(){

   this.controlVariable.dismiss();

}
```